# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, long-integer, bigdecimal

Db table information:

```
fid [NUMBER(32,0)PK]
status [VARCHAR2(10)]
```

DAO class:

```
public Integer Update_bank_dep(Long fid, String status) {
    try {
        String query       = "update WtrBnkdep as wb set wb.wtrbdStus=:status where wb.wtrbdUniqval=:fid";
        Query  queryobject = get_session().createQuery(query);

        queryobject.setParameter("fid", fid);
        queryobject.setParameter("status", status); 
        int cd = queryobject.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("cd=" + cd);

        return cd;
    } catch(RuntimeException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error="+ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Error=java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided enough details to the problem, but obviously it should be converted to `BigDecimal`:

```
queryobject.setParameter("fid", new BigDecimal(fid));
```

Comment: For example, what's the database type of the `fid` column, etc. But anyway, this should be enough to fix it.